# SQL : can not create a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I do the following:

```
use oracle developer

create table loan 
(
        barcode                 number (20) not null ,
        borrowernumber          number (7) ,
        loancurrentdate         date ,
        loanreturndate          date ,
        loanreserveorder        number (20) ,
        paymentdate             date ,
        borrower_borrowernumber number not null
);

alter table loan add constraint loan_pk primary key (barcode) ;
```

Cannot create a table, then change it ...

```
create table loan 
(
    loanno                  INT not null,
    loandate                date not null,
    loanreturndate          date null,
    loanreserve             number (20) null,
    paymentdate             date null,
);

alter table loan add constraint loan_pk primary key (loanno) ;
```

I get the following error. Why am I getting this?

> Error report
>   SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

It also shows "invalid identifier"

Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Or should I delete paymentdate?

---

After delete the wrong comma, the table created.

Comment: "does not work" is not helpful.  Do you get an error?  If so, what is your error.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I don't really understand the action timeline. also when does this error occur?

Comment: you have a wrong comma  after `paymentdate             date null,`   you should remove it

Comment: `use oracle developer ` Is that a Table_Name with a space as delimiter?

Comment: Try adding a statement `GO;` after the table declaration. Also try `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples you posted are correct (apart from that superfluous comma at the end of the second `CREATE TABLE` statement). This are SQL*Plus examples, but - as SQL Developer *emulates* it well, I believe that they should work just fine there too.

The first one:

```
SQL> create table loan
  2  (
  3          barcode                 number (20) not null ,
  4          borrowernumber          number (7) ,
  5          loancurrentdate         date ,
  6          loanreturndate          date ,
  7          loanreserveorder        number (20) ,
  8          paymentdate             date ,
  9          borrower_borrowernumber number not null
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table loan add constraint loan_pk primary key (barcode) ;

Table altered.
```

The second one:

```
SQL> drop table loan;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table loan
  2  (
  3      loanno                  INT not null,
  4      loandate                date not null,
  5      loanreturndate          date null,
  6      loanreserve             number (20) null,
  7      paymentdate             date null
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table loan add constraint loan_pk primary key (loanno) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

What do you exactly mean by saying "Cannot create a table, then change it ..." after the first `CREATE TABLE`? Any error? If so, which one?

"ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" is probably raised by `ALTER TABLE` as you can't *alter* it if it doesn't exist (but the mystery is *why* you can't create it).

"ORA-00904: : invalid identifier" means that you used a column name which doesn't exist in the table, such as

```
SQL> alter table loan modify xxx number;
alter table loan modify xxx number
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "XXX": invalid identifier
```

If possible, do the same as I did - copy/paste SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: The table created. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
drop table loan;
create table loan 
(
    loanno                  INT not null,
    loandate                date not null,
    loanreturndate          date null,
    loanreserve             number (20) null,
    paymentdate             date null
);
```